# Zebra Printer Python Package in Pycharm

Tags: python, printing, zebra-printers

I am trying to install the zebra-0.0.5 package in pycharm on a windows machine. I did have pip and win32 installed. But this error keep showing up. Would someone had similar experience before help?
Thanks!

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32print (from zebra) (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for win32print (from zebra)

Answer (score 1):

The zebra module depends on a module called **win32print** on Windows for the installation to complete. Since the **win32print** module is no longer available anywhere it gives you error.

**Possible Solution 1:**

- Switch to linux as it does not require the win32print module on linux

**Possible Solution 2:**

- Install [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) / [pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32). Install any one of the modules and use it.
- Download zebra 0.0.5 source code from
  [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zebra/0.0.5)
- Extract it and edit the setup.py file and more specifically the line
  23 which says **install_requires='pywin32/pypiwin32'**:

  `if sys.platform.lower().startswith('win'):
      install_requires = 'pywin32/pypiwin32'
  else:
      install_requires = None`
- Now, edit the zebra.py file and change all references from win32print
  to pywin32/pypiwin32.

**NOTE:** I haven't tried this solution as I don't have a zebra printer. I hope this would help you.