# Unable to install zebra python package on Windows machine due to win32print

Tags: python, pywin32, zebra-printers

Using Windows 10 machine (64-bit) with python 3.5.2 installed, I am trying to install zebra package using **pip install zebra** but get below error
Collecting zebra
  Using cached zebra-0.0.5.tar.gz
Collecting win32print (from zebra)
  **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32print (from zebra) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for win32print (from zebra)**

I have installed the latest build (220) of **pywin32** from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/ succesfully and restarted the machine and command shell but receive the same error.

I see a similar question has gone unanswered [Zebra Printer Python Package in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307771/zebra-printer-python-package-in-pycharm#) and am hoping someone has figured this out and can provide me some guidance. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The zebra module depends on a module called **win32print** on Windows for the installation to complete. Since the **win32print** module is no longer available anywhere it gives you error.

**Possible Solution 1:**

- Switch to linux as it does not require the win32print module on linux

**Possible Solution 2:**

- Install [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) / [pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32) (which you have already done). Install any one of the modules and use it.
- Download zebra 0.0.5 source code from
  [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zebra/0.0.5)
- Extract it and edit the setup.py file and more specifically the line
  23 which says **install_requires='pywin32/pypiwin32'**:

  `if sys.platform.lower().startswith('win'):
      install_requires = 'pywin32/pypiwin32'
  else:
      install_requires = None`
- Now, edit the zebra.py file and change all references from win32print
  to pywin32/pypiwin32.

**NOTE:** I haven't tried this solution as I don't have a zebra printer. I hope this would help you.

Comment: I tested your solution and found that I needed to only install Zebra from the source code.  No need to edit the 'install_requires' variable.